# Finding UMP test when testing a simple hypothesis against a composite hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

Hi all I have question regarding the following when reading the notes on Page 5 here: http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~zhu/ams571/Lecture8_571.pdf

The question that I have is when the author showed how to find the UMP test for testing $H_0: \mu=\mu_0$ vs $H_a : \mu > \mu_0$.

The author showed us that we would reject the null when $Z_0 = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \ge Z_{\alpha}$. He said "Furthermore it is easy to show that for each $\mu_1 >\mu_0$, the likelihood ratio test of $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ vs $H_a: \mu = \mu_1$ would reject the null hypothesis at the significance level of $\alpha$ for  $Z_0 = \frac{\bar{X}-\mu_0}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \ge Z_{\alpha}$. "

My question is he said "it is easy to show that for each $\mu_1>\mu_0$, the likelihood test would reject.....", how do we show that?

I was thinking it might have to do with the denominator in the likelihood ratio because it is in the denominator where we adjust the $\mu_1$? So does it mean once we know that we reject the null when $\mu=\mu_0$, we should show that for any $\mu_2,\mu_3,\mu_4...$ bigger than $\mu_0$, we would reject the null of $H_0:\mu=\mu_2$,$H_0:\mu=\mu_3$, $H_0:\mu=\mu_4$? Is this what the author is talking about?

Then how do we show it?

Comment: In this case likelihood ratio test coincides with UMP test, which you can verify using the usual LRT procedure.

Comment: This representation – $H_{0}:\mu=\mu_{0}$ vs $H_{a}:\mu>\mu_{0}$ – is somewhat incoherent, because a true state of nature $H_{0}:\mu<\mu_{0}$ has no representation in either $H_{0}$, or $H_{a}$. I encourage you to revise $H_{0}:\mu\le m_{0}$.

Comment: Yes Alexis, but I don't understand why the author used that for $H_0$.

Comment: Yeah, I *have* seen this notation before. Not a fan. :) Also: My comment should have read "…because a true state of nature $\mu < \mu_{0}$ has no representation…" (the "$H:$ was extraneous and erroneus).

Comment: sorry do you mean the $H_0$ stated in the notes is "unusual"? or actually wrong? Or there could be an $H_0$ like that with the $H_a$ like that also?

Comment: I mean the hypotheses stated in the notes is actually **incoherent:** $H_{0}:\mu=\mu_{0}$ means "I hypothesize the mean **equals** $\mu_{0}$." $H_{a}: \mu > \mu_{0}$ means "I will reject $H_{0}$ if I find strong enough evidence that the mean is **greater than** $\mu_{0}$." But notice that the state of nature $\mu < \mu_{0}$—which is part of a continuous distribution's sample space—corresponds neither to $H_{0}$ nor to $H_{a}$! Hence, if one wants to looks for evidence of this $H_{a}$, the null should be its **complement** or $H_{0}: \mu \le \mu_{0}$.